# Float Datatype is not defined in mongoose-express database schema

Tags: express, backend, mongoose-schema, web-development-server, mongoose-web-server

I am using express with mongoose in mongodB's local type (mongodB compass). I was defining float type of datatype while creating a schema in mongoose, but it is showing me an error [here is the error] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFAGM.png)
what if we have to define float type value like 10000000.25 also what another datatype we can use in place of float?

Note-I tried both float and Float but none is working.

Comment: mongoose-web-server tag should be removed from this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number` type to store floating values in MongoDB

```
equity: { type: Number },
```

OR

You can use the `Decimal128` type.

```
equity: { type:mongoose.Types.Decimal128 }
```

More Clarification about `Decimal128` visit this link https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#Mongoose.prototype.Decimal128